# Getting a commit hash based on a timestamp in Git

Tags: git, git-commit

Is it possible to search commits by a range of timestamps?(or just a specific one or simply prior to a specific date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--before/--after` from `git log` helps to filter the commits of particular time range.

Here is an example that shows all the results in one range:

```
git log --after="2020-01-01 00:00" --before="2020-01-10 23:59"
```

Here is another example for showing the results in one line with prettifying it:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%h %ad %s" --after="2020-01-01 00:00" --before="2020-01-10 23:59"
```

If you want all the commits just before a date you can use only `--before`